SharePoint Rest API for uploading file and metadata from ASP.NET
I am using below code for uploading document with metadata from asp.net application to SharePoint 2019 on-premises. but getting 403 forbidden/401 unauthorized error user account has full access on SharePoint site.
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add Item to SharePoint List</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#addItemBtn").click(function () {
                var itemData = {
                    "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.DemoListListItem" }, // Replace 'YourListName' with your actual list name
                    "Title": $("#titleInput").val(),
                    // Add other fields as needed
                };
                var rdigest = getRequestDigest();

                $.ajax({                  
                    async:true,
                    url: "http://xyz:8800/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('DemoList')/items",
                    method: "POST",                    
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
                        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",                       
                        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),                        
                        "Authorization": "NTLM " + btoa("admin@xxx.com"+ ":" +"xyz")
                     
                        // Replace with your SharePoint username and password
                    }, 
                    data: JSON.stringify(itemData),
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("Item added successfully");
                        // You can handle success actions here
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        alert("Error adding item: " + rdigest);
                        alert("Error adding item: " + JSON.stringify(itemData));
                        alert("Error adding item: " + JSON.stringify(error));
                        // You can handle error actions here
                    }
                });

                function getRequestDigest() {
                    $.ajax({
                        async: true,
                        url: "http://xyz:8800" + "/_api/contextinfo",
                        method: "GET",                       
                        headers: {
                            "Accept": "*/*",
                            "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
                            "Content-Type": "application/xml;charset=utf-8",                          
                            "Authorization": "NTLM " + btoa("sharepoint.admin@nucleussoftware.com:nsel@321")                            
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            var requestDigest = data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue;
                            // Use the retrieved request digest value in your AJAX call
                            console.log("Request Digest: " + requestDigest);
                            // Now you can use the requestDigest variable in your subsequent AJAX calls
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                          
                            console.log("Error retrieving request digest: " + error);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="titleInput" placeholder="Title"/>
    <br/>
    <!-- Add other input fields for additional columns -->
    <button id="addItemBtn">Add Item</button>
</body>
</html>

Please help how to resolve this.
